# Program crashes when listing out vector elements (C++)

Tags: c++, crash

I'm trying to list out the elements of four vectors with a pause after 15 lines of output, so far it does what i want, but it crashes at the end of the function.

```
    void List(vector<string> itemNumb, vector<string> itemName, vector<double> itemCost, vector<int> itemQuant, int length, int index)
    {
        index = 0;
        length = itemNumb.size();
        while (index <= length)
        {
            cout << "======================" << endl;
            cout << itemNumb[index] << endl;
            cout << itemName[index] << endl;
            cout << itemCost[index] << endl;
            cout << itemQuant[index] << endl;
            if (index % 15 == 14)
            {
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
            }
            index++;
        }
    }
```

I just be missing something obvious, getting tired, being new to c++ doesn't help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are iterating outside the vector and thus get a crash just change `index<=length` to `index != length` and it should work

Answer (score 2):

It crashes because when `index` == `length`, the statement `index++` makes the variable increase, `while` gets executed one more time and then you are accessing `itemNumb[length+1]` which is out of boundaries.

Comment: That is why, in my opinion, it is safer to use for loops to iterate through containers/arrays/etc.